# How to parse with jsonSlurper() using if/else statements in Groovy?

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to parse through some JSON and get the status from 'stop-emu'.

```
def stageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response?.content)
stageJson.stages.each { echo(it) }
//status = ????
```

the code above returns the following:

```
16:49:47 [_links:[self:test], id:2, name:test_name, execNode:none, status:SUCCESS, pauseDurationMillis:0]
[Pipeline] echo
16:49:47 [_links:[self:test], id:5, name:test_name, execNode:none, status:SUCCESS, pauseDurationMillis:0]
[Pipeline] echo
16:49:47 [_links:[self:test], id:6, name:stop-emu, execNode:none, status:FAILED, pauseDurationMillis:0]
[Pipeline] echo
16:49:47 [_links:[self:test], id:100, name:del-work, execNode:none, status:SUCCESS, pauseDurationMillis:0]
[Pipeline] echo
```

I'm halfway there, just not sure how to grab the status if name = stop-emu.

Comment: Can you provide how the JSON looks like

Answer (score 0):

to find the first one

```groovy
stageJson.stages.find{it.name=='stop-emu'}?.status
```

if you have and need to collect all of them:

```groovy
stageJson.stages.findAll{it.name=='stop-emu'}.collect{it.status}
```